# Append sum of a column into dataframe without Janitor package

Tags: r

Hi I have a sample dataset like this. What I would like to do is to calculate the sum of column "Number" and append it to the last row. I understand that I can use the package "Janitor" to provide the ideal result but my work device does not have the updated version of R. So I am trying to figure a way to do the same thing.

[image: Sample Dataset]

```
#using janitor library
df = df%>%
 adorn_totals("row")
```

[image: Ideal Result]

Another way of solving it would be to calculate the sum of column using

```
x = sum(df$Number)
```

but I have no idea how to append x into df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `dplyr` with `bind_rows()` function. Here an example using dummy data. Inside `bind_rows()` you have to compute the total value:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
#Data
df <- data.frame(Code=sample(c('YE','RE','PU','WH'),20,replace = T),
                 Color=sample(c('yellow','red','green'),20,replace = T),
                 Number=round(runif(20,1,15),0),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Create total
df %>%
  bind_rows(df %>% summarise(Number=sum(Number,na.rm=T)) %>% mutate(Code='Total'))
```

Output:

```
    Code  Color Number
1     PU yellow      3
2     PU yellow      4
3     PU yellow      8
4     RE yellow      5
5     PU  green     13
6     RE    red      2
7     RE  green      7
8     RE    red     12
9     PU yellow      3
10    YE    red      9
11    WH  green      4
12    RE    red      3
13    RE yellow     12
14    YE  green     14
15    RE  green      6
16    PU yellow     10
17    WH  green      2
18    YE    red      6
19    PU yellow      5
20    PU  green     12
21 Total   <NA>    140
```

Comment: Hi, this work perfectly. Thanks! But may I know what's the function of set.seed?

Comment: @dummy123 Hi! You can omit `set.seed()`. It was only used to generate the random numbers in `runif()`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataset is called `df`, you can use `rbind` and `sum`:

```
rbind(df, sum(df$Number))
```